# Learn when a given tag is most active?

Tags: support

I would like to learn in which part of the day a given tag is most active, so that I will ask my question around that time, in order have the highest chance of getting a useful answer.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you believe that different tags have different times of activity rather than every tag being active equally at the same parts of the day?

Comment: @Xufox Don't know. Just guessed.

Comment: @Xufox SO folks just recently discussed that in podcast - there is significant correlation between local time and activity in particular tags... So it is entirely possible to have noticeable dips in traffic for particular tag at times when activity peak falls into ocean instead of land... or on time when [Jon Skeet is awaiting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9147/195743) :)

Comment: Well, not at the tag level but David Robinson did a similar analysis for programming languages: [What programming languages are used late at night?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/04/19/programming-languages-used-late-night/)

Answer (score 14):

You improve your chances of getting a useful answer by writing a good, clear, easy to understand, question. Choosing a time of day to post the question might shorten the time between the posting and getting an answer.

I suggest the best time of day to post a question is when:

- You are not in a hurry.
- You have time to do your research to see if an answer already exists.
- You have time to experiment and learn why your experiments fail.
- You have time to write a good question and properly explain the problem, your attempts at a solution and your understanding of the problem and the failing attempts.

When you have composed a good question, post it. So it gets exposure to all the experts in all the timezones around the world.